# Using 2 BufferedReaders to read 1 file

Tags: java

So i'm trying to create a 2d character array from a .txt file. The first while-loop calculates to number of columns and rows. The second while-loop is to enter chars into the 2d array. However when i create BufferedReader br2 and use readLine() and then try to print it the line prints out "null". Why does the second BufferedReader start at the end of the file?

```
       public Maze(FileReader reader){
       try {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
           cols = 0;
           rows = 0;
           str = br.readLine();
           while (str != null) {
               if (str.length() > cols) {
                   cols = str.length();
               }
               rows++;
               str = br.readLine();
           }
       }
       catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("Error");
       }
        maze = new char[getNumRows()][getNumColumns()];
       try {
           BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(reader);
           line = br2.readLine();
           System.out.println(line);
           while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line);
               for (int i = 0; i < getNumColumns(); i++) {
                    maze[row][i] = line.charAt(i);
               }
               row++;
           }
       }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
```

this is how I call it from main

```
public class RobotTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Maze maze = new Maze(new FileReader(file));


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @OscarTideman its because you've exhausted the underlying reader.  You might be able to `mark(0)` prior to using the first `BufferedReader` then `reset()` prior to the second.

Comment: Hey @MrR I tried mark(0) and then resetting but it did not work. A quick google and i found an example where they used mark(26) and now it somehow works!

Answer (score -1):

You are using the same reader for initializing both of the BufferedReaders and after the first one finishes reading that means the next one will continue reading at the EOF. You must return the second one to the beginning of the file before iterating again through it.

You can reset the pointer of the reader by using `FileReader.reset()`

You can checkout `mark()` as well in the documentation.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Reader.html#reset()

Comment: Does a FileReader support mark/reset though? I don't really see evidence in the javadocs that it does. BufferedReader supports it.

Comment: FileReader extends InputStreamReader that extends Reader so yes it supports it.

Comment: Not all readers support mark/reset, that is why Reader has a method markSupported(). I suggest you read the javadocs you linked to yourself.

Comment: You are incorrect. Not all readers support mark() but all that extend Reader support reset(). The person clearly uses FileReader in his example. I went ahead and tested both methods before writing the answer.

Answer (score -1):

As the name indicates, a 'BufferedReader' uses a buffer.

There's a reason for that.

Harddisks, network communications, SSDs - these are all concepts that tend to operate in terms of **packets**. They write or read largish chunks. For example, with networking, you can't just 'send a bunch of bytes down a wire' - you need to send a packet, because the packet includes information about where the packet is supposed to go and to solve the ordering issue (when you send packets on the internet, one you sent later may arrive earlier, so packets need an index number on them so the receiver can re-order them in the right way).

If you send one byte, okay - but that'll be ~200 bytes on the wire. Hence, sending 1 byte 5000 times is ~1 million bytes sent, whereas sending 5000 bytes in one go is only 5200 bytes; a 1000x difference!

Similar principles apply elsewhere, thus, 'send 1 byte' or 'read 1 byte' is often **incredibly, factor 1000x** inefficient.

Hence, buffers. You *ASK* for one character or one line (which can be quite a short line) from your `BufferedReader` and it will dutifully give you this, but under the hood it has read an entire largish chunk (because that is efficient), and will be fielding your further requests for e.g. another line from this buffer until it runs out and then it grabs another chunk.

The upshot of all that, is that you **CAN NEVER** use a reader ever again once you wrap it in a bufferedreader. You are 'committed' to the buffer now: That BufferedReader is the only thing you can read, from here on out, until the stream is done.

You're creating another one, and thus, your code is buggy: You're now effectively skpping whatever the first BufferedReader buffered; given that you're getting `null` out, that means right now it buffered the entire contents of the file, but perhaps on another system, a bigger file, it wouldn't return null, but some line deep into the file. Either way, you **cannot** use that filereader anymore once you have created a bufferedreader.

The solution is simple enough: Make the bufferedreader, once, and pass that around. Don't keep making BufferedReader instances out of it.

Also, resources need to be 'protected' - you must close them no matter how your code exits. If your code throws an error you need to still close the resources; failure to do so means your program will eventually get stuck and will be incapable of opening files, forever - the only way out is to completely close the app. Finally, `FileReader` is basically broken; it uses 'platform default charset encoding' which is anyone's guess. You want to 'hardcode' what encoding it has, and usually, the right answer is "UTF-8". This doesn't matter if the only characters are simple ASCII, but it's 2021. People use emojis, snowmen, and almost every language on the planet needs more than just a to z. If your encoding settings are off, it'll be mangled gobbledygook.

The newer Files API (`java.io.File` is outdated and you probably don't want to use it anymore) defaults to UTF-8, which is great, saves us some typing.

thus:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (var reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(args[0]))) {
        Maze maze = new Maze(reader);
    }
}
```